# return function of list isn't displaying on the screen in python

Tags: python

The return function works perfect but somehow return list is not displaying on the screen.

```
def test(lst):
    ls = []
    lst[:] = [ele + 1 for ele in lst] # lst[:] changes the original list

    ls.append(lst)
    return ls

test([1,2,3])
```

Comment: You haven't done anything to _print_ it on the screen.

Comment: you need to print the output `print(test([1,2,3]))`

Comment: I checked your code and if you run that in a jupyter notebook, you don't need any print statement. Otherwise, you do. So, in my opinion there's no problem with you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the return to:

```
return print(ls)
```

or print it while calling the function:

```
print(test([1, 2, 3]))
```

or assign it to a var and print it after:

```
answer = test([1,2,3])
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I see you haven't used the `print` statement.

I think adding this to your code may fix the issue:

```
print(test([1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `test([1,2,3])` within a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (read-eval-print-loop, such as Python in interactive mode<sup>(a)</sup>), the "print" part of that will print out the result for you:

```
>>> def test(lst):
...     ls = []
...     lst[:] = [ele + 1 for ele in lst]
...     ls.append(lst)
...     return ls
... 
>>> test([1,2,3])
[[2, 3, 4]]
```

However, this doesn't happen in the normal course of events, a call to `test` will *evaluate* the function call but do nothing with the result.

If you want to print it, you need to *explicitly* do so:

```
print(test([1,2,3]))
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In this case, Python will print out any result that isn't `None`. You can see this behaviour with the following:

```
>>> None
>>> 42
42
```